# Use the browser back button with pages loaded by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#gnav a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#contents').load(this.hash.substr(1) +'.php')
    });
});
```

That is my jQuery code that loads some content into a div via Ajax.  How can I make use of the browser back button with that code?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [jQuery History Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/history)

Comment: JQuery hashchange Plugin - http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Or jQuery Address: http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/

Answer (score 2):

You could use the HTML5 history APIs described at http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/history.html -- that gives you complete control of back/forward behaviour for your internal navigation.

Comment: Disregard this, I'm only commenting as a bookmark for future reading ;) Also, +1 for the interesting resource.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice jquery plugin called BBQ http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ Easy to use, documentation is on the page

Answer (score 0):

Another plugin you should consider is JQuery Address.  I used it on a project and found it pretty flexible.

Enables "Deep linking" so you can use it to fire ajax calls based on anchor/query string.   http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/